# Append inserting string rather than html

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append an input to the parent div of a select input but the following code is appending a text string rather than HTML.

I understand that the problem is that I'm calling append on a native DOM element rather than jQuery object (which treats strings as HTML) but I'm not sure how to call 'this.closest('.parentdiv')' as a jQuery object

```
$("select").change(function() {
   if (this.value == 'Other') {
      this.closest('.parentdiv').append('<input type="text" value="" name="newinput" >');
   }
});
```

Comment: `this` = native DOM element. `$(this)` = jQuery Object. Given that they share (functionally) identical implementations of `.closest()`, you can use `$(this).closest(...).append(...)`.

Comment: And `this.value` would be `$(this).val()` (maybe not *would*, but for consistency's sake)

Comment: Ah so simple, thanks for the quick answer!